# Problem starting vampirism quests on Morrowind

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I went to Ashmelech cause I wanted to join the Audane clan. I fought the first vampire until I contracted the disease and then left the place, waited 3 days and became a vampire. However when I went back all of the vampires attacked me and I couldn't talk to them. I left again and waited like seven days but the same thing happened when I went back to Ashmelech. What can I do? Thanks in advance.